# How can I put text right side of drop down list HTML

Tags: html, css

[image]

how to all of linked text are at right, 'ngày' is below 'Tại' not  below 19.
My code: (because I set many options, i haven't put the code before. Sorry!)

```
<span>
    <select aria-label="Ngày" name="birthday_day" title="Ngày" >
        <option value="19" selected="1">19</option>
    </select><select aria-label="Tháng" 
    name="birthday_month"  title="Tháng">
        <option value="5" selected="1">Tháng 5</option>
    </select>
    <select aria-label="Năm" 
        name="birthday_year" title="Năm">
        <option value="1998" selected="1">1998</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">
    <a href="#">Tại sao tôi cần phải cung cấp ngày sinh của mình?</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add a `float: left` to the span around the form fields like this:

```html
<div style="width:350px"> <!-- div only for forcing break in text -->


<span style="float:left">
    <select aria-label="Ngày" name="birthday_day" title="Ngày" >
        <option value="19" selected="1">19</option>
    </select><select aria-label="Tháng" 
    name="birthday_month"  title="Tháng">
        <option value="5" selected="1">Tháng 5</option>
    </select>
    <select aria-label="Năm" 
        name="birthday_year" title="Năm">
        <option value="1998" selected="1">1998</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">
    <a href="#">Tại sao tôi cần phải cung cấp ngày sinh của mình?</a>
</span>


</div>
```

Comment: You knew exactly what i want and It works well for me.I add float right in second <div>. Thank you very much @Stefan